# react native fontSize limit

Tags: android, react-native, text, font-size

I was wondering if anyone had any experience with fontSize limit in react-native?

Let's say we have a Text component that renders a huge 'A' character:

```
<Text style={{ fontSize: 273, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'red' }}>A</Text>
```

When one changes the fontSize style to 274 or more, the character A vanishes, even though red border still remains.
This only happens on Android, iOS renders hugh font sizes as expected.

Has anyone had similar problems? Any ideas on how to proceed in order to support higher fontSize is very much appretiated.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced such a problemon my Genymotion android emulator, but the problem doesn't exist on real devices.